# RGBA data layout in local memory that reduces bank conflict

Tags: opencl

What is the best way of layout this out in local memory to reduce bank conflicts ?

I was thinking:

```
RRRRRRRRRRRR...
GGGGGGGGGGGG...
BBBBBBBBBBBB...
AAAAAAAAAAAA...
```

I would like to grab all four channels at once to use in vector operations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Then use "RGBARGBARGBARGBA..." and you can grab all four channels at once to use in a vector. Plus, it's one read instead of 4.

Bank conflicts are caused when multiple work items are accessing different areas that are a certain offset from each other. So your image layout doesn't matter as much as your row pitch when it comes to causing a bank conflict.

Comment: Thanks. Suppose each channel is a 32 bit float, and there are 16 banks in the LDS.  Each work item needs to access two adjacent pixels. So, workitem 0 accesses buf[0] and buf[1], workitem 1 accesses buf[1] and buf[2] etc. So there will definitely be bank conflict. I am just trying to minimize it.   If I use RGBA format, then conflicts may be more severe because four channels are affected in a conflict, instead of one. That is why I was thinking of planar configuration mentioned in original question. What do you think?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert in bank conflicts. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841877/what-is-a-bank-conflict-doing-cuda-opencl-programming. My guess is that once you're reading more than 32-bit per work items the reads get serialized (256 bits at a time) across the work group, and you won't have bank conflicts.

Comment: Yes, good point. Its taking me some time think in terms of SIMT execution.  I am planning on using the vload4 command to load all pixel channels in one go. But Ithink there should still be no bank conflicts in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Running a simple kernel with this architecture on an AMD HD7700 looks very promising. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

On my target architecture, HD7700, the planar configuration gave the best performance: vload4 was much slower.  I think this must be due to bank conflicts, but I am not sure.